# Retrieve Title,Description and thumbnail of a url in php/Javascript/jqueryurl

Tags: php, url, metadata

As we post any url on facebook, it shows its meta-data(title, decription and thumbnail image), How can we achieve same thing in php or scripting language(javascript/jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, Facebook simply parses the html code of the Website behind the link and looks for `<img />` tags. You can then choose any of the found images as picture for your link.

In PHP, you would fetch the websites HTML source via

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://...');
```

Then use regular expressions to find those `<img />` tags.

Answer (score 1):

- you make an ajax hit to your server sending the URL
- on the server side, get the url
- parse it, extract the relevant info
- send back the response as a either as JSON and parse it on the client side, either straight as HTML

Answer (score 0):

There is a good plugin that can be used as a headstart.

It does not fetch the image, but it's a start if you want to implement your own

http://www.webinfopedia.com/extract-meta-data-from-url-using-php.html